# Returning cv:Mat pointer to main function

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, image-processing

I have written a function which belongs to class `panoramic_distance`. This function is returning array of `images/cv:Mat` to main function. But I am bit confused how to access the contents of array of images from main function because attached code is giving me segmentation fault when I call `cv::imshow`.

```
class panoramic_distance 
{  
    cv::Mat* breakimageinstrips(cv::Mat image, bool vertical, int no_strips)
    {      
        cv:Mat split_image[6];
        int d_factor;

        d_factor=image.cols/3;
        split_image[0] = image(Rect(0,0,d_factor,image.rows));
        split_image[1] = image(Rect(d_factor,0,d_factor,image.rows));
        split_image[2] = image(Rect((2*d_factor),0,d_factor,image.rows));
        std::cout<<"\n Image slip in 3";
        std::cout<<" address = "<<split_image;
        split_images1=split_image;
        std::cout<<" addressss = "<<split_images1;
        return split_images1;


        return split_image;
    }     

};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    panoramic_distance p1;
    cv::Mat *images;
    images=p1.breakimageinstrips(t1,1,3);
    std::cout<<" \n"<<images<<std::endl;  
    cv::imshow("This image",*(image));
    return 0;
}
```

if I commment `cv::imshow` then it doesnt give segmentation fault and have following output. This means the address of `cv:Mat` array is transferred to main but I dont know how to access the contents of array.There is nothing wrong with code but problem is how to access `cv:Mat` array contents in main function.

**Output:**

```
0x47d6ecfa0

Image slip in 3 address = 0x7ffe7d6ecbd0 addressss = 0x7ffe7d6ecbd0
0x7ffe7d6ecbd0

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 10ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: Question is, why you even have raw pointers to `cv::Mat` in there -- it works as a smart pointer tracking a reference count, and a shallow copy (which happens by default) is trivial compared to any processing you do on the data. Just return a `cv::Mat` and that's it. And if you really do need to use pointers, then use smart pointers -- C++11 provides them.

Comment: The trick is not to use C-style arrays. Use a `std::vector<cv::Mat>`, and return it by value from your function.

Comment: problem is the scope of cv:Mat split_image[6]; if you really want pointers you'll have to use malloc or new. But better use cv::Mat objects instead of pointers and vectors instead of arrays.

Answer (score 4):

You're returning a pointer to (the first item of) a local array. After the function's returned that array no longer exists. It's called a **dangling pointer**, it gives you formally Undefined Behavior, and is best avoided.

It's very long since I dabbled in OpenCV, but as I recall `cv::Mat` is itself mostly like a smart pointer, that you can just return directly, by value.

Comment: I agree with you but I did same with double array and it worked. May be wont work with cv:Mat. With double I got warning from compiler but still I was able to access memory of function array(local). This might be because that data was still available in memory and not overwritten. But here single element is image which is much bigger in size and might have be overwritten. Is this right?

Comment: Size has little to do with it. It's just not very predictable whether some old stack contents will be overwritten.

Comment: And even if it didn't do shallow copy, returning the cv::Mat by value would still be okay due to RVO/copy elision.

Answer (score 1):

Very sorry for posting bit early. I have solution.

```
     class panoramic_distance
{  
void breakimageinstrips(cv::Mat image, bool vertical, int no_strips, cv::Mat split_image[])

           //cv:Mat split_image[6];
           int d_factor;

                   d_factor=image.cols/3;
                   split_image[0] = image(Rect(0,0,d_factor,image.rows));
                   split_image[1] = image(Rect(d_factor,0,d_factor,image.rows));
                   split_image[2] = image(Rect((2*d_factor),0,d_factor,image.rows));
                   std::cout<<"\n Image slip in 3";
                   std::cout<<" address = "<<split_image;





         }     

};
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 panoramic_distance p1;
 cv::Mat images[6]

 p1.breakimageinstrips(t1,1,3, images);
 cv::imshow("This image",images[0]);
 cv::imshow("This image",images[1]);
 cv::imshow("This image",images[2]);
 return 0;
}
```